# populating a 2nd select box based off the 1st one using ajax and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

I'm going a little nuts here. I know this has been answered a few times before but I can't seem to get it. I must be missing something very obvious.

I need the options of the second select input to be dynamically populated from a DB based on selection of the 1st select input. I have tested the getShowByBand.php code and it produces the intended results. My guess is the problem lies in the javascript file. Please take a look at my code and see if you can help.

**testForm.php**

```
  <form role="form">
    <div class="well" id="generalIDRows">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 padding-top-10">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="band">Choose Band:</label>
            <select id="band" name="band" class="form-control">
              <option value="">Band Name</option>
              <?php 
                       $sql = "SELECT bandID,bandName FROM Band";
                           $bandq = mysqli_query($link, $sql);                  
                       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($bandq))
                 {
                $band_ID=$row["bandID"];
                $band=$row["bandName"];                     
                echo '<option value="' . $band_ID . '">' . $band .'</option>';
                 }
              ?>
            </select>
            <script src="js/getShowByBand.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 padding-top-10">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="show">Choose Show:</label>
            <select id="show" name="show" class="form-control">
              <option value="">--Select Show--</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

**getShowByBand.js**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
 $(".band").change(function()
 {
  var id=$(this).val();
  var dataString = 'id='+ id;

  $.ajax
  ({
   type: "POST",
   url: "womhScripts/getShowByBand.php",
   data: dataString,
   cache: false,
   success: function(html)
   {
      $(".show").html(html);
   } 
   });
  });
});
```

**getShowByBand.php**

```
<?php
$link=mysqli_connect("localhost","womhproduction","Derkadeepd0ng","womh");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    echo "failed to connect" . mysqli_connect_error();
if($_POST)
{
    $id=$_POST['id'];
    $showSQL = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT showID FROM Act WHERE bandID =" . $id . ";");
    $showResults = mysqli_num_rows($showSQL);
    if($showResults > 0)
    {
        echo "<option selected disabled>--Select show--</option>";
        while($showRow = mysqli_fetch_array($showSQL))
        { 
            $showID= $showRow['showID'];
            $showNameSQL = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT showName FROM Shows WHERE showID=". $showID . ";");
            $showNameResults = mysqli_num_rows($showNameSQL);
            if($showNameResults > 0)
            {
                while($showNameRow = mysqli_fetch_array($showNameSQL))
                {
                    $showName = $showNameRow['showName']; 
                    echo '<option value= "' . $showID . '">' . $showName . '</option>';
                }       
            }     
        }       
    } 
}
?>
```

Comment: add a error callback, lets see what it says?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$("#band").change`...  dot is used to select class.

Comment: Thank you so much! I also needed to do the same for ".show" as well, as I'm sure you knew.

Comment: Yup you have to ,I didnt look at that.

Answer (score 2):

try to change this $(".band") to this $("#band") on your javascript you are calling on change for the class you should do it by id.